# Working with key-value list in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I am working with OpenOffice Calc and i want to use some kind of key-value-list given in a spreedsheet; in one cell i want to choose a key from this list, automatically the corresponding value should appear in a separate cell.

So, lets say: I have a spreedsheet S1, which contains in Column A the keys and in Column B the values.

In another spreedsheet S2 i have created a "selection"-list in a specific cell C1 with the same key-values. Now, i want to select a value from this list and "lookup" the corresponding value from the first spreedsheet. This value should appear in cell C2.

What would be the easiest way to "implement" this?

Thanks for any advice.

Alex

PS: By the way, is it possible to use the keys given in Column A automatically as the preview-values of the selection list? At the moment i have added them manually...

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the formula

VLOOKUP(lookupvalue; datatable; columnindex; mode)

In my case

lookupvalue was the "key"-list
datatable was the matrix based on column A and B
columnindex equals to value 2 (B-Column) and 
mode=0 for unordered mode.

Best regards

Alex